# How do I copy unique values from a column to array and trim them?

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem Description:**

I have two sheets, one is a blank report template, and the other contains my data.  Within the data set there's a location ID in Column M.  Each location ID is formatted as , ().  For example, a warehouse located in Miami would be:  "Miami,FL (DIST)" as it is part of the Distribution division.

I would like to import all of the unique values into an array, and then trim the contents so that I end up with an array of just the names of the City.

---

**Superflous Details:**

I thought about doing this in my old "go-to" fashion of advanced filtering the data into a separate sheet, trimming it, and referencing the range, but decided against it.

I would like to learn a bit more about programming with Arrays instead of sheet objects, something that I've avoided since I do not like how VBA handles them vs. other languages that I use where arrays have more dynamic properties.

Answer (score 4):

You may use `WorkSheetFunction.Transpose` method to copy data in a column to Array. It gives you a `index 1 based Single Dimensional Array`. If you have multi columns, the method provides you with a multi dimensional array.

```
Dim arrayV as Variant    
arrayV = WorkSheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A2:A20").Value)
```

To find the last used row in this range, use the following code that will remove any empty cell values being populated into the Array,

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, _
      Sheets(1).Range("A2:A20").Column).End(xlUp).Row 
arrayV = WorkSheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A2:A20").Resize(LastRow-1).Value)
```

Next, to get the unique values, you may use a `dictionary` object as it will only hold unique items.

```
Dim dc as Object
Set dc = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = Lbound(arrayV) to Ubound(arrayV)
   If Not dc.Exists(arrayV(i)) Then
      dc.Add arrayV(i), i
   End If
Next i

'--output to Sheet or do whatever you want with this
dc.Keys() '-- gives you an array with the unique values    

Set dc = Nothing
```